# How to convert 12V 3A Car battery to 5V 1A?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, dc

I want to build a GPS tracker for car for which I need a 5V 1A to power my circuit. The power source being Car battery of 12V 3A, what should I use to get my desired voltage and current?

There will be shrax, current and voltage spikes too. What could be best solution for me to overcome all these and get a constant supply?

Comment: A 3A car battery : that won’t start any car that I am aware of...

Comment: @SolarMike He means 12v outlet for sure.

Comment: Why won't you use an phone charger? Most of them have built-in short circuit protection, that you might wanna need.

Comment: Plenty of dc to dc converters available via the internet...

Comment: What are shrax?

Answer (score 2):

Use a phone charger, the USB socket type put out 5V at upto 2A so that will be plenty for your GPS.

Comment: Can phone charger be directly connected to car battery? or DC DC convertor a good alternative

Comment: get a phone charger designed to in-car use, they are internally DC-DC converters.

Comment: If you look on sites like aliexpress etc, you can purchase modules designed for installing in cars in order to fit USB power outlets.  That's probably your best bet.

Comment: @AbhishekBhandari: there are USB phone chargers made to plug into a car's lighter outlet - no installation or modification of the car's wiring required.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this:

Linear converter, it drops the voltage by "burning up" the current, this makes them inefficient. For example if you are drawing 1A, the 12V-5V=7V drop will consume 7W of power in the regulator with 5W being sourced to your load.

[image]

DC to DC converter:
Usually more than 80% efficient, with efficiencies approaching 95 or 98%. They switch an inductor or capacitor on and off very fast to regulate the voltage, the are more complex and require more external components (although you can buy modules with [only three pins](https://www.google.com/search?q=7805%20dc%20dc%20converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)

[image]